# Create React App build does not work correctly

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am new developer at CRA. I have a project and I had created it with create react app. When I use `run npm run build`, It can not set home page which has only a button for test. I added **react-router-dom** and **homepage:"./"** in my **package.json**. In localhost I can use and see everything correctly but when try it with `npm run build` , I can't reach anything and build shows me empty page. What should I do? Do you have an advice to me ? I dont know anything whether everything works correctly.

App.Tsx:

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { Route, Switch,BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import HomeDashboard from './containers/Home' 
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/home" component={HomeDashboard}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeDashboard}></Route>
          </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

package.json :

```
 {
      "name": "test",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "homepage": "./",
      "dependencies": {
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
        "typescript": "^3.9.7"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "build": "react-scripts build",
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      
    }
```

build folder:
[image]

Comment: I think this is because you need to serve it to see it properly

Comment: Try installing `serve` with `npm install -g serve` and then serve your build directory with `serve -s build`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected. Your built `index.html` refers to all javascript and css files by an absolute link, which will not work if you just open it on your machine.
You have to serve it from a server. Locally you could use the `serve` npm package for that:

```
npm install -g serve
cd ./build
serve .
```

Comment: There is no folder like dist i did not see on my directory. Why?

Comment: Sorry, in your case it's called build

Answer (score 1):

The `npm run build` command simply compiles your react application to pure html, javascript, css.
It does not serve it on your localhost or somewhere else. You can see the built app by opening the /build/index.html with a browser, but this may not work due to realtive paths, routing and cors policies.

You can follow the instructions in the docs and use `serve` to serve it:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Thank you for document. I will follow it in deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party.
I ran into the same problem trying to deploy the application on gh-pages.
This solution worked for me.
Added to my package.json:

```
"homepage": "https://{username}.github.io/projectname/",
```

Added basename to the Router component (BrowserRouter as Router):

```
<Router basename="/projectname">
```