# Blank Page is Showing After building react app

Tags: reactjs, npm-build

After reading several stack solutions like add "homepage":"." in package.json() file, I still cannot get through this.

After `npm run build` a build folder is generated inside my project folder. when I'm opening the build folder and trying to run the index.html file it shows the blank page.
Although `npm run build` works absolutely fine.

````
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  282.86 KB  build/static/js/main.108757a0.js
  3.1 KB     build/static/css/main.8e671453.css```


**Please help me out, I'm a beginner in react and these things make me worry too much **
````

Comment: npm build, does not provide you with static html which you can directly display in the browser. You need to have some kind of server to provide html, js, css and so on :)

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119725/create-react-app-build-does-not-work-correctly/64119811#64119811